# Running PhantomJS in python from php

Tags: php, python, phantomjs

I success to execute a python script in php.

python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf8

from selenium import webdriver
import os
import sys
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
  usr = sys.argv[1]
  pw = sys.argv[2]
  br = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/bin/phantomjs')
  print 'ok'
```

php:

```
$command = sprintf("./login.py '%s' '%s'", $user_num, $password);
exec($command, $out);
echo $out[0];
```

browser (it work!):

[image]

however, It is not work when I use PhantomJS in python script.

when I use PhantomJS ('print' moved)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*-coding:utf8

from selenium import webdriver
import os
import sys
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
  usr = sys.argv[1]
  pw = sys.argv[2]
  br = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/bin/phantomjs')
  print 'ok'
```

browser(not work..):

[image]

I checked permission of PhantomJS, and it was rwx-wx-x.

What's the possible problems?

Comment: It probably didn't work the first time either. Why `print 'ok'` before launching PhantomJS first time and after  - the second time?

Comment: @Vaviloff It mean, launching PhantomJS code make error clearly. (Both codes are almost same condition - except order of print and launching)

Comment: `launching PhantomJS code make error clearly` Sorry, didn't catch that. The important thing is - does the script work when you launch it from the shell? Are there errors?

Comment: @Vaviloff It is no problem when I launch python script from the shell.